# How Do I Return Template From Meteor Template Helper?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

My HTML:

```
<template name="foo">
    {{#each category}}
         {{#if this.custom}}
              {{> someTemplateName}}
         {{else}}
              {{> generic}}
         {{/if}}
     {{/each}}
 </template
```

How do I return some value to `someTemplateName' so that I can switch templates based on on the object in the #each statement.

```
 Template.foo.someTemplateName = function () {
      return A_TEMPLATE_NAME
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was actually very simple.

```
 <template name="foo">
     {{#each category}}
        {{#if this.custom}}
          {{> someTemplateName}}
        {{else}}
          {{> generic}}
       {{/if}}
     {{/each}}
 </template>
```

And I return a helper:

```
Template.foo.someTemplateName = function () {
    return Template[this.name];
}
```

Where this.name is from the `{{#each}}' context.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is the following :

JS

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  someTemplate:function () {
    return Template.someTemplate;
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="someTemplate">
  <p>SOME TEMPLATE</p>
</template>
```

It is not really the name that you manipulate but template objects which live under the variable name `Template.myTemplate`.

If you want to manipulate template names, try `UI.dynamic` :

HTML

```
<template name="foo">
  {{> UI.dynamic template=someTemplateName}}
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  someTemplateName:function () {
    return "someTemplate";
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks! I saw your post a little late. The implementation that I derived is very similar.